# How to make it refresh in JavaScript and not affect the HTML?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, sql

I have a code that is working super ok but I don't know how it to put JavaScript into it to check if there is one extra result in my table "chat" and if there is it should refresh the page and if the result hasn't changed then not to refresh page, sorry but I have no idea when it comes to JavaScript.

chat.php

```
require('checkformessages.php');
...
```

checkformessages.php

```
$sqlmessages = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat");
$numbermessages = mysql_num_rows($sqlmessages);


// JavaScript script (no idea what it's supposed to be
// but some kind of timer checking if there is new result in the database)

if($numbermessages===$Javascriptcheck) {
//do nothing
} else {
//it should refresh the chat.php because its required in the page
echo "<script>window.location = window.location.href;</script>";
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is rather too broad, and could do with some more research. However, I don't mind adding some notes to get you on the right track:

1. AJAX requests originate from the browser. If you are periodically checking something, perhaps you need a JavaScript timer that makes a request to the server.
2. Since this is a read operation, a `get` operation is fine. Your script may read items from the query string and then respond with a suitable message format. JSON is popular these days.
3. Your returned data would probably be best as an array of new messages. You can indeed return just a boolean, and refresh the whole page if new rows exist, but this is rather wasteful. You might as well just return new rows in the AJAX reply.
4. To get just new rows, you'll need to a timestamp in this table, and send the last known timestamp to the server with the AJAX operation. The new rows are the ones that have a timestamp larger or equal to the supplied value.
5. The jQuery `get()` method is probably suitable.

I would recommend using the above to get you started - you may need to research each with a search engine, which I would encourage. If you still get stuck, working through some examples/tutorials online might also be helpful.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks , So Best Suitable for me is Number 5. JQuery I guess ... But I still don't see how JQuery can count rows , Lets see what I could Find :)

Comment: jQuery can't count database rows. But JavaScript can find out how many rows you've rendered in the DOM (or, alternatively, the timestamp of the most recent row) and then send an AJAX request to see if there are any new ones. The AJAX op can query the database, either by count or by timestamp.

Comment: I definitely don't trust timestamp because some sites like mine are worldwide viewed and they get late responses or Different timezone And its too confusing + another column in the table , But Javascript , How exactly does it count rows hard to believe that javascript can do that, I know a tiny bit of javascript But never used it to anything got to do with mysql ...

Comment: JavaScript cannot count rows in the database, as I have already said. It can count rows in HTML (e.g. how many `<div>` blocks you have rendered).

Comment: You don't need to worry about browser timezones in JavaScript here: just render the timestamp for the youngest row somewhere in JavaScript. Your first page rendering can render a `var youngestTimestamp = ...;` and then this can be reset by AJAX operations.

Comment: Sure then thats no use , Im counting results in a database its completely different , What I need to do is only to be done by AJAX I think ... There is no way once PHP sets You cant do nothing about that ... I guess making some kind of public variable could help me Use the set PHP with the refreshing one and one Javascript taht maybe checks if PHP.set = or not = to PHP that checks every few seconds

Comment: I think you just haven't understood the approach I've suggested, which does indeed use AJAX. My recommendation to try some AJAX tutorials is the best way forward from here, I think - it is a very broad topic, and it is better for you to read a book than for me to write one in an answer.

Comment: You see I don't need to find how to use AJAX or learn it either, I prefer PHP for everything and Javascript for some other things . And my goal is to keep out of other language and focus on these ... If Id have to look for how its all done , Id probably have to change everything ... and my aim is still to keep it as much PHP as possible :)

Comment: What you are asking is not possible without AJAX, sorry!