# Check Variables of different scripts to match in PHP

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, mysql, ajax

Sorry for confusing everybody Ive made tons of scripts but it seems that I got how to explain what I am really trying to acomplish this time :)

```html
chat.php
<?PHP
require('connect.php');
$sqlmessages = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat");
$oldmessages = mysql_num_rows($sqlmessages);
echo $oldmessages;
//so It displays 43 from database NEXT :)

m.php
<?PHP
require('connect.php');
$sqlmessages = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat");
echo mysql_num_rows($sqlmessages);
//this displays also 43 messages ... now As for this page I don't care what happens to it and where its displayed as long as the chat.php is not affected by it this page is a check if this will go to more or less than the value of the chat.php if there is difference then send some kind of code to refresh that page
```

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate of your previous question, for which I have given you a number of pointers. What is the purpose of this new question?

Comment: Good Point , This question is based on a new teory with sesions witch is different

Comment: A session is not going to help. If you want to find out, in JavaScript, whether there are new rows available without refreshing the page, you need AJAX.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [halfer answered](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29732263/1311025) in your other question, you basically need:

1. A timer (with an interval that never ends)
2. An AJAX request inside that timer to a PHP file
3. A PHP file that queries the database

Maybe you need a more clarified explanation of how to do it. Take the following answer as a tutorial of how to do AJAX calls.

Before we go you must understand this:

- JavaScript/jQuery is executed in the browser.
- PHP is executed in your server.

---

For the timer/interval we will be using `setInterval` javascript function. So grab your editor and create a new JavaScript file. Name it `script.js`, for example.

Put this inside:

```
setInterval(function() {
    $.get('getNewChatMessages.php', function(number_chat_messages) {
         $('#chat_messages_count').text(number_chat_messages);
    });
}, 5000);//every 5 seconds make a GET request to CHAT.php
```

The line
`$('#chat_messages_count').text(number_chat_messages);`

Is:

1. `$('#chat_messages_count')` gets the div that has an id "chat_messages_count"
2. text(number_chat_messages); sets what is in the variable `number_chat_messages` in HTML.

`$('#chat_messages_count').text(number_chat_messages);`
With this, we are setting `number_chat_messages` to the div with id `chat_messages_count`.

---

Now grab your editor again, and create a new HTML file. Lets name it, `index.html`.

Put this content inside:

```
<html>
<body>
<p>Number of chat messages:</p>
<div id='chat_messages_count'></div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
<body>
</html>
```

See, we load jquery and then our script.js.

---

Now let's create the PHP file. Let's name it `getNewChatMessages.php`. Why? Because in the `$.get` function we call it that way.

```
<?php
$sqlmessages = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM chat");
echo mysql_num_rows($sqlmessages);
```

That's it. No refreshes, no PHP headers with refresh and that weird stuff. Try it and learn it, and then adapt it to your code.

Comment: Wow , thankyou for writing this for me ... it dosent work just gives no value after number of chat messages: but still a great effort

Comment: in getNewChatMessages.php when I access it it sais 43 which is correct number but in index sais nothing but the <p>Paragraph

Comment: So Id appreciate if you tell me what is actually wrong ... thanks :)

Comment: Dude thanks I put the div after the incliding of script.js and closed </script> and its working WOW thanks :O

Comment: sorry, I missed that lol

Comment: Well I got something working now XD At least something to work with ... but what has jquery got to do with the javascript?

Comment: jQuery is for $.get --> https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/ and text() --> https://api.jquery.com/text/ and the selector by id --> https://api.jquery.com/id-selector/

Comment: Yush but this Is a start I guess to proof that it could work ... It seems like Id have to do a lot of work to make it all working ^^ But thanks ^^